# how to fix unresolved project references after vs2015 update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015, updates

I updated my visual studio 2015 with visual studio 2015 update 3
 After update I also update Azure tools 
when I start new project I got error that there is unresolved project references for

```
 entityframework
entityframework.sqlServer
microsoft.identity.core
microsoft.owin
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just have to install the packages by my self 
but why ?????

Comment: I just have to go to tools>>extensions and update>> and add the core tools

Answer (score 0):

I just have to go to tools>>extensions and update>> and add the core tools